# Why 13.04 Raring is not in http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/

Tags: release-management

I'm trying to install software (bundlebee) from the old 13.04 ubuntu release following [this instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release) but it isnt working.

I think thats because in http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ there aren't a raring folder.

Comment: Looks like it is still available at http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/

Comment: Then I don't know why I cant install Bundlebee :S http://askubuntu.com/questions/447133/problem-installing-bundlebee

Comment: Because bumblebee repo doesn't contain anything for 13.04. See - https://launchpad.net/~bumblebee/+archive/stable -> `Published in:` filter

Comment: Oh thanks, I see... will be beter install a previous version (12.04) of bundlebee or the next one (13.10)?